# URL routing in mvc

Tags: model-view-controller, url

I have this url working in my code:

`http://localhost:12345/home/index/<parameter1>/<parameter2>/<parameter3>/<parameter4>`

I want to change my url to NOT to include the home/index `(<controller>/<action>)`.

My current Global.asax entry is like:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
   "Default", // Route name
   "{controller}/{action}/{parameter1}/{parameter2}/{parameter3}/{year}/{parameter4}", // URL with parameters
   new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", parameter1= "", parameter2= "", parameter3= "", parameter4= ""} // Parameter defaults
   );
```

Please let me know how can i change it
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Should be as simple as removing those parameters from the URL since you have them in the Defaults dictionary.

routes.MapRoute(
   "Default", // Route name
   "{parameter1}/{parameter2}/{parameter3}/{year}/{parameter4}", // URL with parameters
   new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", parameter1= "", parameter2= "", parameter3= "", parameter4= ""} // Parameter defaults
   );